# How to get the projection matrix in EasyAR

Tags: vuforia, easyar

Vuforia provides an easy way to get the projection matrix using the following code
`VuforiaUnity.GetProjectionGL`. Going through the EasyAR documentation, I could not find any similar method. Please suggest if any such method exists.

Answer (score 0):

`CameraDevice` has a method called `projectionGL`:

- https://www.easyar.com/doc/EasyAR%20SDK/API%20Reference/2.0/CameraDevice.html#projectiongl

Example usage can be found in their demo projects (see `HelloAR.java`).